# RegEx close to what I need.

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't have much experience with RegEx. I have a textbox that I want to validate with JavaScript.

^(\d{0,5}.\d{0,4})?$

This is pretty close to what I need, except this will allow 6 digits before the decimal if nothing comes after the decimal. 5 digits before the decimal and 4 digits after should be the max. I want anything under that to be allowed.

Ex: 123456 is valid when it shouldn't be.
123456.1 is not valid and shouldn't be.

Part of js function:

```
 if (document.getElementById("txtPrice").value !== "") {
     var RegEx = /^(\d{0,5}.\d{0,4})?$/;

     if (RegEx.test(document.getElementById("txtPrice").value) == false) {
     alert("Contract Price is entered as an invalid format.");

     return false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: you'll need lookback which javascript doesn't have. perhaps splitting the string would be easier.

Comment: you need to escape `.` with `\(backslash)` in your code, otherwise it will be treated as *any* character and that's why `123456` is valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\.`. `.` matches any character a single time, `\.` matches a dot character:

```
^(\d{0,5}\.\d{0,4})$
```

If you don't want to enforce use of decimal point enclose the last part inside a non-capturing group:

```
^(\d{0,5}(?:\.\d{0,4})?)$
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I need.